Connecting to OData API iteratively each time with a different URL in Fabric
I am trying to connect to OData API from Fabric, I wanted to call different URLs iteratively passed dynamically to the OData and as a result we receive tables. Among them we wanted to select few tables and create either a table or a JSON file.
The kind of authentication that is supported is only Organizational Account, where this authentication method is not supported in Manage connections and Gateways it was supported only in Dataflows.
The challenge was how do I dynamically pass URL and authentication parameters dynamically to Dataflow to Dataflow Gen2 in Fabric
How can I implement the above scenario, can some one help me on this.
I have tried using in Manage connections and Gateways it failed due to authentication type that I require was Organizational Account, where this is not allowed.
So I tried in Dataflows and using this Dataflow I have created a Dataflow Gen2 to get the tables into lakehouse.
The challenge was I need to pass the different URL each time iteratively and dynamically through a pipeline how can I do this.

You can't change the whole URL, or the Dataflow won't know what authentication options to use.  So the base URL must be static, but you can change the RelativePath and Query portions of the URL dynamically. eg:
Web.Contents(
 "https://data.gov.uk/api",
 [
  RelativePath="3/action/package_search",
  Query=[q="cows"]
 ]
)

Using The RelativePath And Query Options With Web.Contents() In Power Query And Power BI M Code
